# Linux TCP Server - listen on multiple ports in C++

Tags: c++, linux, unix, tcp, port

I am having a problem with a tcp server. I would like to listen on multiple ports to respond to clients. It should be a kind of event based. Each port indicates another type of response. I read a lot about epoll, poll, select or multithreading. I tried to work with a lot of examples from books like Unix Network Programming. But probably I need a few trigger keywords. How could I start properly?

Hopefully my questions are easy to understand. 
Appreciate each answer!

TO NARROW IT DOWN THERE IS MY IDEA...
I started thinking of this:

If I am have a "Server Manager" with a lot of Server, can I do it as follows?

CreateSockets(ServerList);
CheckSockets(SocketList,  master_set);

Within the Server Manager: 
1) for loop to create all server sockets (functions: socket/setsockopt/ioctl/bind/listen)

```
void CreateSockets(map<int,ServerType> ServerList)
{
    fd_set        master_set;
    map<int,ServerType>::iterator it;
    map<int,int> SocketList;
    for (it= ServerList.begin();it!= ServerList.end();it++)
    {
        listen_sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (listen_sd < 0)
        {
            perror("socket() failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
        rc = setsockopt(listen_sd, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR,
                (char *)&on, sizeof(on));
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            perror("setsockopt() failed");
            close(listen_sd);
            exit(-1);
        }
        rc = ioctl(listen_sd, FIONBIO, (char *)&on);
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            perror("ioctl() failed");
            close(listen_sd);
            exit(-1);
        }
        memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
        addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        addr.sin_port        = ((*it).second->Port);
        rc = bind(listen_sd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            perror("bind() failed");
            close(listen_sd);
            exit(-1);
        }
        rc = listen(listen_sd, 32);
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            perror("listen() failed");
            close(listen_sd);
            exit(-1);
        }
        SocketList.insert(make_pair(((*it).second->Port),listen_sd));
        FD_ZERO(&master_set);
        max_sd = listen_sd;
        FD_SET(listen_sd, &master_set);
    }
}
```

Next:
 2) Some how wait for some events within the server manager (Select with a list of socket descriptors)

```
void CheckSockets(map<int,int> SocketList, fd_set master_set)
 {
    fd_set working_set;
    do
    {
        memcpy(&working_set, &master_set, sizeof(master_set));
        ready_descriptors = select(max_sd + 1, &working_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (ready_descriptors >0)
        {
            desc_ready = rc;
            for (i=0; i <= max_sd  &&  desc_ready > 0; ++i)
            {
                if (FD_ISSET(i, &working_set))
                {
                    desc_ready -= 1;
                    if (i == listen_sd)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            new_sd = accept(listen_sd, NULL, NULL);
                            if (new_sd < 0)
                            {
                                //error
                            }
                            FD_SET(new_sd, &master_set);
                            if (new_sd > max_sd)
                                max_sd = new_sd;
                        } while (new_sd != -1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            //Go into server and recv and send ( Input Parameter = i)
                            CheckServer(i);
                        } while (TRUE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {endserver=true;}
    }while(endserver=true;)

}
```

3) Go into the server and process the question (recv/send)????

```
    void CheckServer( int sd)
 {
    rc = recv(sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

    //some stuff in between

    rc = send(i, buffer, len, 0); 
 }
```

Could this work?

Some parts are used and changed from the IBM nonblocking IO source Code.

---

thank you for all your help. I was able to get something done, BUT one thing still dont work.

What I did until now:

1) The consrtuctor of the individual server includes the socket operation. 
2) I am able to return the socket id and save it within the server manager.
3) The manager has a for loop which contains the select command to check for any event on the sockets.
4) if something happens, all affected socket will sequentially repsond.

My problem is:

It works fine if I am always connect and disconnect while i am requesting data from the server.
When my client is configured in a way that the connection will be hold, everything is blocking, since my code is waiting for a disconnect.

Here are the code snippets for each part:

1)

```
       Server::Server() 
    {

    listen_sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    ret = setsockopt(listen_sd, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&on, sizeof(on));
    ret = ioctl(listen_sd, FIONBIO, (char *)&on);

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port        = htons(Server_Port);
    ret = bind(listen_sd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    ret = listen(listen_sd, 32);
    Socket = listen_sd;
}
```

2)

```
Socket= new_Server->GetSocket();
SocketList.insert(make_pair(Socket,new_Server->ServerID));
```

3)

```
 while (TRUE)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&working_set);
        for (i=0;i < max_conn;i++) 
{
            if (SocketArray[i] >= 0) {FD_SET(SocketArray[i], &working_set);}
        }

        ret = select(max_sd+1, &working_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    desc_ready= ret;
        for (i=0; i <= max_sd  &&  desc_ready > 0; ++i)
        {

            if (FD_ISSET(i, &working_set)) //jeder Peer der was hat
            {
                desc_ready -= 1;
//delete all loops to get the correct object 
                        (Server).second->DoEvent(i);

            }
        }
    }
```

4)

```
new_sd = accept(new_sd, NULL, NULL);
    if (new_sd < 0)
    {
        if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            perror("  accept() failed");
        }
    }
do
{


    rc = recv(new_sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
//edit datastream and create response
            rc = send(new_sd, buffer, len, 0);
        if (rc < 0)
        {
            perror("  send() failed");
            close_conn = TRUE;
            break;
        }

    }while (TRUE);
```

I just delete the errorhandling dor listen/bind etc. just to shorten the code here... Originally it is in there.

Comment: This question is too broad, please narrow it down to something that can be answered.

Comment: have you checked out [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) already? that has all the basics (in c style, though).

Comment: Have a look into the reactor pattern...

Comment: I wonder if there's not already some class/library.

Comment: I need non blocking server sockets. What i would like to program: 1)Establish all necesarry sockets 2) wait for an event at one or more of these sockets 3)if event than respond to each request on these particular sockets... My problem is to convert this idea into source code since i am not sure which commands would be the best for me... while considering runtime, response time and limits of max amount of sockets ... Hopefully I narrowed it down a bit

Comment: I am not sure why this question is too broad? It is okay for a custom application to listen for multiple ports and how would one use select in such cases?

Answer (score 3):

Roughly here are the steps: You can have multiple TCP servers (aka server sockets) listen for each port. Next, you can use a select() and pass file descriptors for each of these server sockets. If you get a connection on any of these, then select would return a read event and mark the fd  of the server socket that has the connection. YOu would need to call accept() on that server fd.

YOu cannot make a single TCP socket listen on multiple ports.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking of select, but i dont want to have any timeouts - so i need non blocking server sockets. I s that possible with select? Since accept does wait right?

Comment: Select is a blocking call. You can specify a timeout as a parameter to select, but not specifying it (which means passing it as NULL) would mean select would timeout only when there is an event (read event in this case). Btw, you can always have multiple threads and one thread can do select for all the server fds.

Comment: Thank you. So one more question. If I am have a "Server Manager" with a lot of Server, can I do it as follows? Within the Server Manager: 1)for loop to create all server sockets (functions: socket/setsockopt/ioctl/bind/listen) 2) Some how wait for some events within the server manager (Select with a list of socket descriptors) 3) Go into the server and process the question (recv/send)????

Comment: Yes, you would need to create TCP servers (bind/listen stesp) for each port -- using a for loop would be okay. Next, you can use select and pass file descriptors of each server in the select fd set and wait for read-event (please read about select!). Once you have an incoming connection, the select owuld unblock and return the fd (or fds) of servers that have a pending connection. We can call accept() on these fds. The accept() would return the fd of child connection and we can do recv/send on this child fd.